# how to select from mysql table from matlab variable (array/cell)

Tags: mysql, matlab

I have a table like this

[The table in mysql](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ggt3S.png)

and I have a variable x in matlab

```
    x=[1 5 6 8 10 21 99];
```

now I want to select like this

```
    select * from tablename where key1 = x
```

I know mysql query must be string, and my variable x in matlab may be **too long**.
So how to do this in matlab? I failed in searching. Thanks

```
    conn = database('instancename','username','password');
```

I know I can do this like

```
    sql = 'select * from tablename where key in (1,5,6,8,10,21,99)'
```

The question is my x isn't constant and sometime could be a 1*N cell ( whose element is char), I want to put it into a script.

Comment: Are you able to connect to a SQL database through MATLAB yet and you are just asking how to construct your query string? Or are you asking how to connect from MATLAB at all?

Comment: yes I'm able to connect to the database. I'm asking how to construct query in matlab script @Dan

Comment: Please add the code you use to connect to the DB. There are many ways to do this in MATLAB. Specify if you are using a toolbox

Comment: Also what do you mean by `key1 = x`? Do you mean `key1 in x`?

Comment: yes,  key1 in x. and my x isn't constant I want to construct a query. Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQL Server you write your query like this:

```
select * from tablename where key1 in {1, 5, 6, 8, 10, 21, 99}
```

I don't know about MY SQL but I imagine it is very similar. Which means all you need to do is convert `x` to the string `'1, 5, 6, 8, 10, 21, 99'` which you could do like this:

```
x_str = strjoin(cellstr(num2str(x'))',',')
```

and now the whole query becomes

```
query = sprintf('SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE key1 IN {%s}', x_str);
```

As an aside, another way to create `x_str` could be:

```
x_str = sprinft('%d, ', x);
x_str(end) = [];
```

Comment: Thanks, seems no better way. I thought I could input the x directly into mysql's memory and then let mysql use it as a condition.